# why domains like mail.google.com or music.youtube.com not work wit www

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-hosting, website

If we try to access [www.mail.google.com](http://www.mail.google.com) or [www.music.youtube.com](http://www.music.youtube.com). They wouldn't work. why? Also if we want how can this be achieved

Comment: Because nobody created those DNS records. They didn't deem them necessary.

Comment: Or/and because nobody added those names into virtual hosts on the web server that serve related applications. For what you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Why would they?

`www` is nothing special. It is just one string (name, label) among any other combination, for computers it makes no difference. And not all hostnames have to start with this prefix.

When the World Wide Web was invented, it was **custom** to name website with hostnames starting with `www.` just to more easily distinguish them from other hostnames, like those of an FTP server starting with `ftp.` or an SMTP/POP/IMAP server starting with `mail.`, etc.

> Also if we want how can this be achieved

The owner of the zone has to create the relevant DNS records if the names need to resolve. But given the names you used as example - which are obviously not yours -, why are you concerned?

Comment: needs to implement the same i.e. need to redirect requests from www to non www. Also checked that www.drive.google.com works but www.mail.google.com doesn't. why so?

Comment: Because someone in Google just didn't make the DNS entries for it. And they did for `www.mail.google.com`. No one here will be able to answer that question, you'd have to ask Google.

Comment: @kannuchopra "needs to implement the same i.e. need to redirect requests from www to non www." Then you should post that as question, with your own specific details, instead of wondering why others did their setup in one way or another. But better, do search first the various SE sites because there are already millions of questions about "redirections".

Comment: @kannuchopra "Also checked that www.drive.google.com works but www.mail.google.com doesn't. why so?" Why not? Each owner of a name is free to have, or not, whatever names it wants below it, so why are you trying to infer anything special about a specific name existing or not?